# Which is the correct spelling: "grey" or "gray"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, orthography, north-american-english, commonweath-english

What is the difference? Or is there any? Which would be more British English?

Comment: I was once docked points on an elementary school spelling quiz for spelling it grey -- the spelling I was more used to seeing in the books (mostly by British authors) that I read.

Comment: I have to say... this is a bit of a gray area.

Comment: Does anyone not think that _grey_ has a particular emotional mood than _gray_ doesn't possess? _Gray_ is just a color. _Grey_ on the other hand, has an emotional valence: I'd always prefer to say _I was feeling grey to-day_ or _The sky was a dreary shade of grey_, over substituting _grey_'s counterpart in its place.

Comment: Try using *greigh*.

Comment: Both *grey* and *gray* are correct.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) has 5445 cites for *grey* and 1092 cites for *gray*. The [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/), on the other hand, paints the following picture:

[image]

<sub>(X axis: year, Y axis: incidences per million words.)</sub>

After seeing these stats, it should come as no surprise that Wiktionary marks [*grey*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grey) as *British, Canadian*, and [*gray*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gray) as *US*.

Comment: Of course, some of those instances will also be proper nouns.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The question is, you thought of Grey's Anatomy or Sasha Grey?

Comment: I've added an answer that takes into account proper nouns: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/178758/61410

Comment: What would Zane Gray say about this??

Answer (score 58):

I grew up in England for chunks of my childhood and early adulthood and am still around people who originated from the UK, so I still encounter both spellings all the time. The easiest way to remember it is that the 'a' in gray stands for 'America' and the 'e' in grey 'England'.

Comment: I like the mnemonic!

Answer (score 35):

I have found out about Google NGrams. It is really useful for such questions. The gap between the two spellings was important during WWII, then was really narrow, and finally it has been widening since the 1980s.

[American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grey%2Cgray&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3): [image: "grey" vs. "gray" ngram graph]
[British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grey%2Cgray&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3): [image: "grey" vs. "gray" ngram graph]
[English (cumulative)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grey%2Cgray&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3): [image: "grey" vs. "gray" ngram graph]

Answer (score 9):

According to the Associated Press (AP) Styleguide, 'grey' is only used in the word 'greyhound' -- otherwise the appropriate use is always 'gray'.  In America, anyway.

Comment: Except for Gandalf the Grey.

Comment: @TRiG but he wasn't American :-)

Comment: @Josh Probably would all be speaking the language of Mordor now if he was! ;-)

Comment: According to Etymology Online, the grey in *greyhound* has nothing to do with the color: > greyhound - O.E. grighund, from grig- "bitch" + hund "dog" (see hound). The name usually is said to have nothing to do with color, and most are not gray. The O.N. form of the word is preserved in Hjalti's couplet that almost sparked war between pagans and Christians in early Iceland: > Vilkat goð geyja,
**grey** þykkjumk Freyja > I will not blaspheme the gods,
but I think Freyja is a bitch

Comment: I wonder if the US edition would change to "Gandalf the Gray" ...

Comment: @GEdgar No! Tolkien’s careful choices of spelling and punctuation are unaltered for American audiences.  I never spell it *gray* myself, anywhere.  Just looks wrong.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers correctly stating that grEy is British English and grAy is American English...

Proper names (capitalized Gray) in British English (red line) account for more than 50% of the instances of the American spelling, Gray.

[image]

[N-grams link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28Grey%2F%28grey+%2B+Grey%29%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28Gray%2F%28gray%2BGray%29%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28Grey%2F%28grey+%2B+Grey%29%29%3Aeng_us_2012%2C%28Gray%2F%28gray%2BGray%29%29%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28%28Grey%20/%20%28grey%20%2B%20Grey%29%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28Gray%20/%20%28gray%20%2B%20Gray%29%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28Grey%20/%20%28grey%20%2B%20Grey%29%29%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28Gray%20/%20%28gray%20%2B%20Gray%29%29%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%28%28Grey%20%2F%20%28grey%20%2B%20Grey%29%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28Gray%20%2F%20%28gray%20%2B%20Gray%29%29%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28Grey%20%2F%20%28grey%20%2B%20Grey%29%29%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28Gray%20%2F%20%28gray%20%2B%20Gray%29%29%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc1)

Answer (score 2):

They're interchangeable. With both spellings available, some people like to assert that they denote slightly different hues. But they don't, consistently.

Answer (score 1):

"Gray" is generally the American spelling and "grey" the British.