# "Grayed out" or "Greyed out"?

Tags: synonyms, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Gray' vs 'Grey'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5390/gray-vs-grey)

Which one is correct? Is it "[Grayed out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayed_out)" or "Greyed out"? Google brings almost the same number of results for both. Can they always be used interchangeably?