# Is it grayscale or greyscale in Canadian English?

Tags: word-choice, differences, canadian-english

I know that [grey is used in Canadian English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5390/which-is-the-correct-spelling-grey-or-gray) - does that then mean that it should be greyscale in Canadian English?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117463/discussion-on-question-by-kylejrp-is-it-grayscale-or-greyscale-in-canadian-engli).